# Retrieving username and password from Dropbox file

Tags: vb.net, dropbox

I have a login tool which grabs the username and password from a file in my dropbox account.

```
Dim prequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://dl.dropbox.com/s/jb4m5udkt96a43z/premuim.txt")
Dim presponse As HttpWebResponse = prequest.GetResponse()
Dim psr As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(presponse.GetResponseStream())
Dim premium As String = psr.ReadToEnd()
```

That's the code I am using, it downloads the file and gives me the text inside. So I used this about half a year ago and it worked fine, now I am trying to use it but it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Did you debugged the code to see at which step you get "off track" ? Also maybe just a typo here and not in your real code but your link contains "prem**u**im" ; should'nt it be "prem**iu**m" instead ?

Comment: yes i did. Well when im trying to get the content i do for example: Textbox1.Text = premium

Comment: @Sehnsucht Just a typo yes, corrected it but that wasnt the Problem, i forgot to say, the error is in the 2nd line (The connection to the remote server can not be established.) But the link is working..

Comment: I just tried to go to the url and got an [error 401](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) which seems to be related to credentials missing ; you should look into the documentation to know how to give those credentials to your request (not my area of expertise)

Comment: Well it doesnt work anymore because i changed the name, the new link is:  http://dl.dropbox.com/s/dwptubndradi3iu/premium.txt?dl=0 ..

Comment: Try using this version of the link instead: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dwptubndradi3iu/premium.txt?dl=0 (using https:// and dl.dropboxusercontent.com)

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use [WebClient.DownloadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: @Greg unfortunatly it doesnt change anything, same error.

Comment: @Sehnsucht yes, i actually would be, but i tried it also and it gives me the same error and i dont know why :(

Comment: @MarcelFTW not giving the actual error message doesn't really help

Comment: the error is in the 2nd line (The connection to the remote server can not be established.)

Comment: oh sorry I missed it from your previous comment ; but that's beyond my knowledge in that specific field.

Comment: This works for me: curl https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dwptubndradi3iu/premium.txt?dl=0 Does it work for you? Maybe something on your machine/network/etc. is blocking the connection.